# Position of matplotlib axes in pixel units

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to set the distance of matplotlib axes in a tkinter canvas to the edges in **pixel units**. Using `ax.set_position()` the position of the axes are relative to the figure, and upon resizing the figure the axes labels and ticks [are cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXpWp.png). Is it possible to keep the margins and only resize the axes area?

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("600x400+200+200")

        self.fig = Figure((18,12))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        
        self.ax.set_position([0.06, 0.06, 0.88, 0.88])
        
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Comment: Yes, use constrained_layout.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you!